# Should I use Priority Queues for scheduling tasks (functions, etc.) in a highly dynamic system?

Tags: c++, multithreading, game-engine

I am a hobby programmer interested in dynamic systems like game engines etc. and I had the Idea of a task scheduling system using something like a priority queue to sort different tasks dynamically and maybe include a parallel feature to use multiple cores efficiently. My explicit idea was to use some kind of Task class that itself stores a function pointer and two queue parameters, one being the gravity of the task and one being the time since it was pushed onto the queue, which then would be multiplied to archieve the position in the listing.
Now here comes my question. Would such a system be more efficient in general or at least pay up in any way in comparisation to a hard-coded system (like some 'main loop')?
**e.g. is it a better solution / is it faster?**
Thanx for the replies.

Comment: Typically compilers can optimize loops. I don't know how much optimization can be provided to PQs with function pointers.

Comment: As always, *benchmark* and find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what priority queue's where designed for.  Start your design with priority queues and see how well it goes.  Then you may want to tweak it if specific issues come up.

Comment: But my question is if using them together with function pointers will pay up. Is it faster than hard coded loops?